# Vision at night

Tags: moonlight

I'm wondering if it's possible to be able to assess the level of light available to the human eye provided by the night sky and celestial objects. I'm interested in the night of 15th June 2019 at Rosses Point, County Sligo Ireland, co-ordinates 54°18′33″N 8°33′58″W. I would also like to understand how the position of the moon and its distance/angle from Earth at any time of the year could have an impact on night light.

Comment: If you are investigating the Peter Bergmann case, note that this was 10 years earlier, 15 June 2009.

Comment: Generally nearby lights have far more affect on night vision than the Moon unless you've specifically taken measures to reduce them.

Answer (score 1):

The moon rose at 20:02 and set at 04:39 on the morning of the 16th June (Happy Bloomsday) The sun set at 22:09 and rose the next day at 04:59, with civil twilight starting at 04:03.  The moon was nearly full, but would have been low in the sky, only 16 degrees above the horizon.

It would have been one of the least dark nights of the year. I can't find complete weather records, but it was a cool night, dropping to 6*C and so probably clear. There was no rain, and no wind

All these records were found on timeanddate.com

The phase of the moon has a big effect on its brightness.  At full moon, especially in winter when it is high, it will light up the ground. The best way to experience the brightness is to go out at night.  During New Moon, the darkness when you are far from city lights can be intense, (however the stars are superb). When the moon is full, it can provide sufficient illumination to see shapes, or make it possible to follow a path.  But really the only way to understand is to experience it.  Fortunately it is quite easy, since it gets dark every night.  The next full moon is next week (at the time of writing).

The distance of the moon has some effect, but it is much less important than the phase.